# Foreign key definition in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

Cant add foreign key constraint in sqlite ...........

Answer (score 7):

As of SQLite 3.6.19, SQLite supports foreign keys. You need to enable them via:

**sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;**

They are turned off by default for backwards compatibility.

See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) for more details.

Comment: Direct link to this info: http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable

Answer (score 1):

sqlite [does not enforce foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ForeignKeyTriggers).

Comment: As romandas says, it does have foreign key support after 3.6.19.

Answer (score -1):

in sqlite 3 :
examples :

```
create table student (_id integer autoincrement primary key ,master_id integer);
create table master (_id integer autoincrement primary key , name varchar(30) );

select * from student where master_id in (select _id from master where name like '...')
```

Don not need foreign key (master_id) references master(_id) ;
:)