# Enabling Foreign key constraints in SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, ado.net, foreign-keys

I'm using SQLite with C# and have some tables with foreign keys defined.

Now, I know that by default foreign key constraints are not enforced in SQLite, but I'd like to turn them ON.

Is it possible to do this through code? I have looked up a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124424/foreign-key-definition-in-sqlite), but I'm not sure how to do it through C# code. I'm using the latest plug-in of SQLite available for Visual Studio 2008 for designing my tables.

```
conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
conn.Close();
```

I need this change to persist when this connection is reopened. Is it possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Finally figured this out from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288871/foreign-key-support-in-sqlite3?answertab=oldest#tab-top). The PRAGMA foreign_key setting does not persist but you can set it every time the connection is made in the *ConnectionString*. This allows you to use Visual Studio's table adapters.

1. Make sure you have the [latest version](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) (1.0.73.0) of system.data.sqlite installed (1.0.66.0 will not work).
2. Change your *ConnectionString* to `data source=C:\Dbs\myDb.db;foreign keys=true;` (replace C:\Dbs\myDb.db with your sqlite database).

Comment: I was using version 1.0.66.0 then. I went ahead without the foreign key feature. Its nice to know that this issue is finally resolved. I'll keep it in mind for any future work. Thanx

Comment: I tried all other methods mentioned in this post, and only this one worked for me.

Comment: I am shocked that in 2020 SQLite still disables foreign key constraints, *even after explicitly **enabling** them*! Talk about major data corruption.

Answer (score 6):

Turn on the pragma:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

You can execute this just like any other SQL statement.

Comment: I'm using SqliteDataAdapter, it manages opening and closing of connections. I believe when a connection is closed, this information is lost. How can I make this information persist?

Comment: @kaustubh: You are right, the foreign_key pragma is session-local. I don't know how SqliteDataAdapter works, but it seems to take a SQLConnection parameter in its constructor. Could you issue the pragma against the connection when you create it?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to specify this information in connection string. Is there some way to specify a command that is executed each time a connection is opened?

Comment: @kaustubh: I meant that you should create a SQLiteConnection, invoke the pragma statement on it, and then use the connection to construct the SQLiteDataAdapter.

Answer (score 5):

I too struggled with this issue. I decided to investigate the full connection string generated in `SQLDriverConnect()` when connecting to the database. This is what it returned:

```
'Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=C:\Users\Staples\Documents\SQLLiteTest.s3db;StepAPI=;SyncPragma=;NoTXN=;Timeout=;ShortNames=;LongNames=;NoCreat=;NoWCHAR=;FKSupport=;JournalMode=;OEMCP=;LoadExt=;BigInt=;PWD='
```

As you can see there is a `FKSupport` property.
After adding `FKSupport=True;` to my connection string it returned this:

```
'Driver={SQLite3 ODBCDriver};Database=C:\Users\Staples\Documents\SQLLiteTest.s3db;StepAPI=;SyncPragma=;NoTXN=;Timeout=;ShortNames=;LongNames=;NoCreat=;NoWCHAR=;FKSupport=True;JournalMode=;OEMCP=;LoadExt=;BigInt=;PWD='
```

And voila! foreign key contraints are enforced.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to do the "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON" with every query.

```
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbSQLite + ";Read Only=False;");
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
    mycommand.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON";
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mycommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=x";
    mycommand.ExecuteReader();
    connection.Close();
```

If you put it in a function to which you pass the CommandText you can reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

These should provide the information you're looking for:

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q22

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable

In short, versions before 3.6.19 don't enforce foreign keys at all, but they can be simulated using triggers; starting with 3.6.19, foreign keys can be enforced, but this needs to be enabled per connection using the `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` statement, and sqlite must be compiled with trigger and foreign key support enabled (which I'd expect to be the case for any binary distribution).

Comment: I'm using SqliteDataAdapter which manages opening and closing of connections automatically. How do I, then enforce this PRAGMA each time an Update is made?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your connection string: `";EnforceFKConstraints=Yes|True|1;"`

Comment: I was euphoric on seeing your reply, seemed like the perfect solution.. But alas, it doesn't work :( Maybe Sqlite data provider for .NET doesn't support it yet.. If it does, then I'm at my wit's end how to make it work..

Comment: @kaustubh: Try to use [dbFacade](http://krez0n.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/files/dbFacade.zip). Maybe it supports that? [Author's blog](http://krez0n.org.ua/archives/84) unfortunately is in Russian (he is from Ukraine, seems to be), but I can try to help you to translate

Comment: @kaustubh: btw, have you added `EnforceFKConstraints=Yes` or `EnforceFKConstraints=True` or `EnforceFKConstraints=1`. Or all of them at once?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just execute the SQL command `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` on your DB connection just like you would a Select or an Update statement. Though you have to make sure your SQLite was compiled with foreign keys and such. See [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Answer (score -2):

```
In C++ store app the following code helped me to enable PRAGMA foreign_keys
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_prepare(db, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;", -1, &stmt, 0); 
sqlite3_step(stmt);

I called this after creating db using the call of 

int rc = sqlite3_open16(path->Data(), &db);
```