# migrations in rails (sqlite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, sqlite

hey I have a small problem with my `rake`

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.integer :broadcast_id
      t.integer :position
      t.string :title
      t.string :location
      t.string :link
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :time
  end
    add_foreign_key :events, :broadcast_id, :broadcasts
  end

  def self.down
    remove_foreign_key :events, :broadcast_id, :broadcasts
    drop_table :events
  end

end
```

problem => **add_foreign_key :events, :broadcast_id, :broadcasts**

**$ rake db:migrate**

```
== CreateEvents: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:events)
-> 0.0021s
-- add_index(:events, :broadcast_id)
-> 0.0004s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: near "FOREIGN": syntax error: ALTER TABLE "events" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("broadcast_id") REFERENCES "broadcasts"(id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you defining foreign keys this way?

If you want a relationship between your `Events` and `Broadcasts` then you should look into creating an active record relation. Something like

```
# Event model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broadcast
end

# Broadcast model
class Broadcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

This way you let rails maintain the foreign key relationship for you. Check out the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on active record associations for more info.

Comment: Additionally, foreign key support in sqlite is [a bit more involved](http://www.justatheory.com/computers/databases/sqlite/foreign_key_triggers.html).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  
Now I have saw that not in my models, it is a total bullshit code for rails!!

Comment: @Dty, What do you mean by "let rails maintain the foreign key relationship for you." ? I stil lneed to invoke rails generate migration AddBroadcastToEvent references:broadcast    . am I right ?

Comment: @Yonatan, no. When you use something like `belongs_to` with `has_many` in rails you don't have to manually create the foreign key references.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers: "The references helper does not actually create foreign key constraints for you. You will need to use execute for that or a plugin that adds foreign key support."

Comment: My concern with this approach is with race conditions, should the foreign key support not be in the database to ensure data integrity?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.6.19, SQLite, aka the default development database, supports foreign key constraints, but enforcement of foreign key constraints is [turned off by default](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) (for backwards compatibility), to fix it:
**Suggested option**:

Use another database such as mysql/postgresql as your development
    database in Rails, and below is an example:

> default: &default
>   adapter: mysql2
>   encoding: utf8
>   pool: 5
>   username: user
>   password: password
>   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
>
> development:
>   <<: *shared
>   database: db_development

**Other options include**:

1. Future versions(4.*) of SQLite has [enabled foreign key constraints in default](https://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/design.wiki), but as of now, it's not released yet.
2. We could also enable foreign key support by the following command:

   `sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`
   `sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys // should print 1`

   But please note:

   - it does not persist and you have to do it on every connection;
   - If `PRAGMA foreign_keys` print nothing, it means your version of SQLite does not support foreign key, please upgrade to 3.6.19 or higher version;
3. Some says we could enable it in connection string, but I didn't find out the correct string in Rails. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613087/1193680).