# Foreign key support in SQLite3

Tags: c#, sqlite, foreign-keys, system.data.sqlite

According to [this](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2159/8788.aspx) thread from 2010, an "EnforceFKConstraints" connection string property was supposed to be implemented into future releases of SQLite. Does anyone know if the developers have gotten around to doing that?

If not, is there another way I can enable foreign key support without doing "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" on each connection? I need this to make sure that deletes always cascade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Future development of System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET provider for SQLite is done by [this group](http://system.data.sqlite.org). The project is currently in migration status and some features are even unavailable now (which were available in 1.0.66 version, which is last maintained by [Robert Simpson](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) (original library author)).

According to latest source code available in [trunk](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/dir?ci=trunk) "EnforceFKConstraints" is not supported. However there is `foreign keys` connection string property which have default value of `False`, maybe it does the job? Try including `foreign keys=True` property in your connection string. Be sure to use latest stable build from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

**Update.** After looking deeper in source, I'm almost sure that this connection string property is doing exactly that you want.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I needed to update from 1.0.66 to the latest version you linked.