# Foreign Key constraint failed - SQLite with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I have two tables in database with `1 to Many` relationship like this:

**Job:**

`iID`, `Other columns...`

**Mailbox:**

`iID`, `iJobID`, `Other columns...`

where

a `Job` can contain many `Mailboxes` and `iID` column of both tables is set to `auto increment`.

The `Mailboxes` are added in collection of `Job` and the parent entity (`Job`) is then added to database and `SaveChanges()` is called, like this:

```
Job foo = new Job
{
  strJobName = "fooJob",
  //other properties...

  Mailboxes = collectionOfMailboxes;
};

dbContext.Jobs.Add(foo);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

where

**Mailboxes** is the child collection property generated by EF.

Everything works fine up to this point. `Mailboxes` and `Job` both are added to database with foreign key relation.

But then I needed to `enable the foreign key constraint` for which I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124433/3621001) that SQLite **doesn't enforce** it by default. So I did it by adding

**`foreign keys=true;`**

in the connection string, which I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289107/3621001) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6419268/3621001) but after adding the constraint I'm no longer able to add a `Job` record. and I get:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: constraint failed
>   FOREIGN KEY

If I remove the constraint then my code works fine. Why is this happening and how can I add foreign key constraint in EF so that it is checked after adding the record.

Comment: I think you will need to make the foreign key nullable, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189701/how-to-get-entity-framework-code-first-and-nullable-foreign-key-properties-to-wo

Comment: I tried by setting the `id` property as `Nullable` in generated entity class but it didn't work. Let me try by adding it with `model builder`.

Comment: @stuartd: not working. I tried this `modelBuilder.Entity<Mailbox>().HasOptional<Job>(m => m.Job).WithOptionalPrincipal();
`

Comment: it might help to [trace the Sql statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: @stuartd: I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer ?

Comment: @John: sadly, no. I had to enable the foreign key attribute, because it was a must requirement. As a workaround for this issue, I switched to adding the entities in their tables separately.