# FK relation not working on SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two tables, **theme** and **quiz**, here is their definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "theme" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "nom" VARCHAR NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE quiz(
     id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     nom        VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
     theme      INTEGER NOT NULL,
     niveau     INTEGER NOT NULL,
     pass       INTEGER DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL,
     jok        INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
     etat       INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (theme) REFERENCES theme(id)
);
```

The field `id` (the primary key) in the table **theme** is a `Foreign Key` in the **quiz** table.

When i try to insert a record in the table quiz which contain the value 30 for example as a foreign key, the record is inserted successfully in the `quiz` table although there is no record in the theme table with the `id = 30`.

Wasn't supposed to interdict this insert since i had a Foreign key constraint?

Comment: Which sqlite version do you use?

Comment: Actually, `AUTOINCREMENT` is not necessary for a serial and automatic id: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905859/is-there-auto-increment-in-sqlite

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Are you sure [foreign key support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) is enabled?

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled,
>   it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Comment: For those who are looking for how to enable foreign key support you need to change your ConnectionString to "data source=C:\Dbs\myDb.db;foreign keys=true;" (replace C:\Dbs\myDb.db with your sqlite database). For original post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254371/enabling-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlite/6419268#

Comment: Apparently, `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`, doesn't work if you are using a in-memory database. I did my own testing with a simple Python script. Just to mention this caveat which I detected during my tests.