# sqlite, how to avoid insert new record when I delete parent? I use C# and EF 4.4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

Well, in SQLLite there is not exist the possibility to delete on cascade, or I don't know how.

Imagine that I have two tables, Table A and Table B. The table B has the IDtableA field, because is a child, and imagine that I have the following situation:

1.- user A load record 1 from TableA and load it in the context.
2.- user A load all the child records from table B.
3.- user B add a new record to table B that is child of table A.
4.- user A save changes and delete record 1 and all the childs that he loaded in the first time, but not include the new child add by the user B.

So in SqlLite I don't have a model, neither realationships between tables, when user B add a new child, not check if the parent exists.

is it posible ensure reference integrity in Sqlite?

Thanks.

Comment: Your reputation was not found (404) but it found it to you by upvoting your question :) :) it is 411 now :)

Comment: this may be usefull http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: thanks for all, the reputation and the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite supports foreign keys and "on delete cascade", but in the new versions.

You can see this article in official SQLite website:

[sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

The say:

> This document describes **the support for SQL foreign key constraints
>   introduced in SQLite version 3.6.19.**

Also, you have to explicitly [enable foreign keys](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) for every connection.

this question may help you: [Enabling Foreign key constraints in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254371/enabling-foreign-key-constraints-in-sqlite)

You can do it by changing the connection string and add:

```
foreign keys=true;
```