# How to use Foreign key concept in Sqlite Manager for Xcode projects?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, firefox-addon, foreign-keys

i want to use foreign key concept in sqlite database.
How can it possible in Firefox SQLite Manager?
Please give me reply to my mail id:
anand.handsinfotech@gmail.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key definition in sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124424/foreign-key-definition-in-sqlite)

Comment: Sorry, that's not how SO works. Check this page periodically for answers, or click the checkbox at the bottom to get automatic email notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can [read here](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/manager/smstructure.htm) how to use foreign keys in SQLite manager.
In short use line below when you create your table.

```
FOREIGN KEY(foreign_key_field) REFERENCES parent_table_name (parent_key_field)
```